# Possibilities when one thread requests that another thread be cancelled

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

What are the various possibilities when one thread requests that another thread be *cancelled* ?

Comment: One possibility is that I could sit down and eat a piece of cake.  Maybe you could add a bit more relevant information to make your question a bit clearer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for the help. I am very new in this website!

Comment: I don't think people can read minds on other web sites either.  Wherever you post, you still have to actually explain the problem is that you want help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thread may be in one of three states with regard to thread cancellation.

- The thread may be asynchronously cancelable. The thread may be canceled at any point in its execution.
- The thread may be synchronously cancelable. The thread may be canceled, but not at just any point in its execution. Instead, cancellation requests are queued, and the thread is canceled only when it reaches specific points in its execution.
- A thread may be uncancelable. Attempts to cancel the thread are quietly ignored.

When initially created, a thread is synchronously cancelable.

---

Source: http://www.makelinux.net/alp/029

Comment: Related: [Windows → Dev Center - Desktop → Terminating a Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686724(v=vs.85).aspx) and [MSDN: Thread.Abort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta(v=vs.110).aspx)